# SQL Server partitioning across multiple file groups

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I am analyzing the partition strategies for SQL Server. I came across two choices as follows for allocating the files to partition.

1. Placing the partitions on the same filegroup
2. Placing the partitions on multiple filegroups

**Question**

When I tried the second approach by creating multiple file groups, partitions, assigning separate physical files for them and populated some data, I am not able to see the data in the physical files. `last modified date` of the file is not changing when new data is populated.
Is it expected? If we create different files for different partitions, won't data get stored on these files?

When I verified the number of rows per each partition after populating the data, I can see the count as expected for each partition.

Please find the queries used to create file groups and partitions. Am I missing anything in the query?

```
ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILEGROUP sc_2022_jan;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILEGROUP sc_2022_feb;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILEGROUP sc_2022_mar;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILEGROUP sc_2022_apr;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILEGROUP sc_2022_may;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILEGROUP sc_2022_jun;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILEGROUP sc_oth;

DECLARE @ValueDatePartitionByMonthFunction nvarchar(max) = 
N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION created_date_half_function (date) 
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (';  
DECLARE @i date = '2022-01-01';  
WHILE @i < '2022-06-01'  
BEGIN
SET @ValueDatePartitionByMonthFunction += '''' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(10)) + '''' + N', ';  
SET @i = DATEADD(month, 1, @i);  
END
SET @ValueDatePartitionByMonthFunction += '''' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(10))+ '''' + N');';  

EXEC sp_executesql @ValueDatePartitionByMonthFunction;  
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME created_date_by_month_scheme
AS PARTITION created_date_half_function
TO (sc_oth,sc_2022_jan, sc_2022_feb, sc_2022_mar, sc_2022_apr, sc_2022_may, sc_2022_jun);

--Some statements to drop existing clustered index and create new one containing the partitioning columns

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILE     (
    NAME = sc_2022_jan_file,
    FILENAME = '/home/admin-pc/Documents/scpartitions/sc_2022_jan_file.ndf',
        SIZE = 10 MB, 
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
        FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) TO FILEGROUP sc_2022_jan;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILE     (
    NAME = sc_2022_feb_file,
    FILENAME = '/home/admin-pc/Documents/scpartitions/sc_2022_feb_file.ndf',
        SIZE = 10 MB, 
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
        FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) TO FILEGROUP sc_2022_feb;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILE     (
    NAME = sc_2022_mar_file,
    FILENAME = '/home/admin-pc/Documents/scpartitions/sc_2022_mar_file.ndf',
        SIZE = 10 MB, 
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
        FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) TO FILEGROUP sc_2022_mar;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILE     (
    NAME = sc_2022_apr_file,
    FILENAME = '/home/admin-pc/Documents/scpartitions/sc_2022_apr_file.ndf',
        SIZE = 10 MB, 
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
        FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) TO FILEGROUP sc_2022_apr;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILE     (
    NAME = sc_2022_may_file,
    FILENAME = '/home/admin-pc/Documents/scpartitions/sc_2022_may_file.ndf',
        SIZE = 10 MB, 
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
        FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) TO FILEGROUP sc_2022_may;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILE     (
    NAME = sc_2022_jun_file,
    FILENAME = '/home/admin-pc/Documents/scpartitions/sc_2022_jun_file.ndf',
        SIZE = 10 MB, 
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
        FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) TO FILEGROUP sc_2022_jun;

ALTER DATABASE sc_mf_test
ADD FILE     (
    NAME = sc_oth_file,
    FILENAME = '/home/admin-pc/Documents/scpartitions/sc_oth_file.ndf',
        SIZE = 10 MB, 
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
        FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
    ) TO FILEGROUP sc_oth;

--query used to verify the count of each partition
SELECT 
    p.partition_number AS partition_number, 
    p.index_id,
    f.name AS file_group, 
    p.rows AS row_count
FROM 
    sys.partitions p
JOIN 
    sys.destination_data_spaces dds ON p.partition_number = dds.destination_id
JOIN 
    sys.filegroups f ON dds.data_space_id = f.data_space_id
WHERE 
    OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'sales'
ORDER BY 
    partition_number;
```

Comment: SQL Server does not update the file timestamp on each write so this is expected.

Comment: Isn't this just your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74685422/partitioning-across-multiple-file-groups-in-sql-server)?